# Double queue synchronization and performance

Tags: python, concurrency, synchronization, queue, amqp

I have a background job processing system using AMQP. Multiple servers are consuming jobs from the same queue. Each of these servers is running 4 worker processes. So far so good.

Now the job itself to be processed, needs some IPC, as to keep it consistent, I use AMQP queue (different one of course) again. The idea was that each worker, will have it's IPC counterpart, like this:

```
                      /    IPC queue   \
Main queue ---> * W1 /                  \ W1-counterpart
              > * W2 /                  \ W2-counterpart
              > * W3 /                  \ W3-counterpart
              > * W4 /                  \ W4-counterpart
                     \ IPC Result queue /
```

The counterparts can operate independently, so it's OK if W3-counterpart is processing a job for W1. The problem is, I noticed, that the system doesn't seem to be fully utilized all the time. Even if the main queue if full of jobs, it seems that only 2 are processed concurrently, in a different moment, all 4 are used. Why? Why isn't this working all the time?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding some debugging print's or similar, of the result when you ask if the incoming queue(s) are empty/nonempty.

Comment: I don't get it, what do I achieve/acquire with this?